# Google Maps draw circle around radius search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm drawing a circle the size of the radius over which I'm performing a nearby search:

```
  // Point where to search  
  var searchArea = new google.maps.LatLng(25.435833800555567, -80.44189453125);

  // Draw a circle around the radius
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: searchArea,
    radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#0000FF",
    fillOpacity: 0.4
   });          
   circle.setMap(map);  

   // Perform search over radius
   var request = {
        location: searchArea,
        radius: parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3, //convert miles to meters
        keyword: "coffee",
        rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE
      };
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);         
    }
```

I then plot markers. This works fine but in some cases markers show outside the circle leading me to believe that it might not be the same size as the radius.

Here is a very good example of what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnPRh/2/

Notice how markers show outside the circle. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to calculate the distance from the center point. I've set your radius into a variable called `RADIUS`, make sure to place it where it is executed after the document has loaded.

I've also modified your `for` loop to include distance check. The `distance` function accepts 2 arguments which are both of type `google.maps.LatLng`

```
var EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137; // meters
var RADIUS = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1609.3);

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function distance(pos1, pos2) {
    var p1Lat = pos1.lat(),
        p1Lng = pos1.lng(),
        p2Lat = pos2.lat(),
        p2Lng = pos2.lng(),

        dLat = deg2rad(p1Lat-p2Lat),
        dLon = deg2rad(p1Lng-p2Lng),

        a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(deg2rad(p1Lat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(p2Lat));

    return EARTH_RADIUS * (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)));
}



for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (distance(results[i].geometry.location, searchArea) <= RADIUS) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that is a lot of math. Doesn't the radius search request already handle the distance from the center point? I simply just want to draw a circle representing the radius in which I'm searching.

Comment: lol it's the haversine forumal, to be honest I don't know anything about math, but I use this function almost everyday in my code.


I'm not sure how the search works, but based on what I saw in your sample page, maybe it fetches results based on latlng bounds, which is a square, not a circle.

Comment: The radius search uses a latlng point and creates a radius around it in meters. For that reason the formula might not be needed because the API makes all the calculations. In my case the circle I'm drawing to represent the radius doesn't seem to be the same size as the radius itself even though I'm entering the same meters for radius and the same latlng.

Comment: That's true actually. Maybe it's got something to do with one result considering the curvature of the Earth and the other not, and giving slightly different output?

Comment: Yes I think you're right! The Haversine formula might be useful in that case.